# Sliver polygons, vertex, gaps

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I'm correcting a Land Use polygon, interpreting a drone image using QGIS. When I use the cut tool and merge tool to edit, the polygon leave a smalls polygons like a line, or sometimes leave a vertex from other polygon neighbor outside, like a line too. This issue won't let me work fast. Is there a tool or configuration to avoid this?
[image]

this is an example of this situation, thats white line is actually a thin Polygon

Comment: Please include before and after screenshots that display your problem.

Comment: Check this link, it may work, but it will only slightly change the shape of the original polygons based on their buffering: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317208/removing-narrow-polygon-dangles/317229#317229

Comment: Did you look at the list of related questions on the right side of this page, under the header **Related**?

Comment: yes, but don't response what I want. I need to prevent it.