# How to clean polygons with too much nodes outside of them?

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, vertices

I have a layer of MultiPolygon, some of them have too much nodes resulting to this :
[image]

Is it possible to automatically delete the nodes that makes extra lines in my polygon or I am doomed to clean it by hand ?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317208/removing-narrow-polygon-dangles/317229#317229

Comment: to complete BERA's links it is called erosion, the idea is to buffer in with a negative value and just affter to buffer out with the same value. This aim to remova all part of geometry thinner than the given buffer radius.