QGIS - Delete lines resulted from Symmetrical Difference/Clip
I used the symmetrical difference command with two shapefiles but the resulting layer containes lines due to minimal differences (see example picture below)

Is there a way to automate the removal of these? The shapefile is very large with many of these errors so doing it by hand would take a lot of time.
I tried fixing the geometry and the check validity but both did not help with this problem.

Search for spikes or dangles. For example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317208/removing-narrow-polygon-dangles


Apply a small negative buffer
Apply a positive buffer, a bit larger buffer distance than in step 1
create the intersection of the initial polygon with the one from step 2

To do this with Geometry Generator or Geometry by expression, use this expression:
intersection(
    @geometry,
    buffer(
        buffer(@geometry,-0.3),
        0.35
    )
)

Blue: initial polygon; red: result:


For "Difference", you can use the "Grid size" parameter to avoid such spikes in the output.
If you specify a value for this parameter, this will have the following effects:

Coordinates will be rounded if the precision grid specified is less precise than the input geometry. Duplicated vertices will be dropped from lines and polygons.
Line and polygon geometries will be removed if all vertices are closer together than the grid size or, for polygons, if they become significantly narrower than the grid size.
Spikes or sections in Polygons significantly narrower than grid_size after rounding the vertices will be removed.

For data where polygons are snapped, but not topologically sound, using a grid size >= 0.00000001 (10e-8) cleans up all lines in the output of a "Difference" overlay operation in my experience.

